# Read from realm.io and add to listview

Tags: android, database, listview, realm

I want to use **Realm.io** to save data and then display each item in a listview.
Here is how I have create the database (I think):

```
config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("timeLog")
            .schemaVersion(42)
            .build();

realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Then after this when I save my data I do the following:

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    timeData logTime = realm.createObject(timeData.class);
    logTime.setWorkedHours(timeTotal);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    System.out.println(logTime);
    System.out.println(logTime.getId());
```

And now I want to add this to an array maybe and display it in a listview.
So I thought i could make something like this:

```
RealmResults<timeData> result = realm.where(timeData.class).findAll();
    result = result.sort("sgnumber", Sort.DESCENDING);
    ArrayList<timeData> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0;i<result.size()-1;i++){
        System.out.println(arrayList.add(result.get(i)));
    }
```

This did not work. And also I dont know if the **db** i created in the first place, cant find it on the phone anyway.

**UPDATE**

```
listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Comment: adapter? Do I need an realm adapter thing? The documentation is not the best on Realm.io

Comment: In order to use a listview, you need an adapter. I suggest you check this article first http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Now I have added an adapter there is nothing. I wonder if the Realm code is correct

Comment: Please update your question with your adapter code and the way you are setting it up

Comment: @Cheskos update is done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116315/discussion-between-cheskos-and-alexander-mogren).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause was that the OP was not creating a custom adapter. A ListView requires the creation of a class that extends from a type of adapter [purposeful to each use case](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and override at least the `getView()` method.