# Where is the id of a string array stored or where can i create one, IN ANDROID Programming?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am learning Android programming from this tutorial about `ArrayAdapter`s and `ListView`s.

The output does not show the string array values but instead shows: Item1, subitem1,, Item2,subitemm2...etc.

I want to know why did it happen? Do the values of string array need to be created separately or does Eclipse do that automatically? If so, where would I put/find the id `mobile_list`?

Here is the main activity class where string array declared:

```
package com.example.ListDisplay;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListDisplay extends Activity {
// Array of strings...
String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173430/read-from-realm-io-and-add-to-listview). You need to create your own class that extends from ArrayAdapter and override `getView()` so you can inflate your views accordingly and `getCount()` so the list view knows how many items are drawn. You are not supposed to use the default implementation of the ArrayAdapter. The default implementation and the way you are using it is taking as second parameter a TextView reference and you appear to be passing a layout. Refer to [the official docs for this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). That's why you need to create your own class

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
```

To

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
```

Comment: Modified it, still no change in the output.

Comment: initialize mobileArray inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)